# Powershell: Register service with network-service account results in error 1068

Tags: windows, powershell, service

I'm basically running this powershell-command (with an elevated powershell-prompt):

```
New-Service -name MyServiceName -binaryPathName "C:\myservice.exe -m myArgument" -Description "MyDescription" -displayName "MyDisplayName" -startupType Manual -credential $mycreds
```

Beforehand I run this to generate $mycreds (the service name is the correct name for network-service in german):

```
$login = "NT-AUTORITÄT\Netzwerkdienst"
$secpasswd = (new-object System.Security.SecureString)
$mycreds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($login, $secpasswd)
```

When I now lookup the service in the windows service manager, I see this under its logon settings (the screenshot is in german but you can get that the credentials seem to have been passed correctly):

[image: Service logon settings with correct service account name]

When I now start the service, I get this error:

```
1068: ...“the dependency service or group failed to start”.
```

This error makes no sense since there is no dependency to this service.

If I now however open up the logon-settings,

1. set them to "Local System"
2. click apply
3. set them to "account:" and enter the account name (NT-AUTORITÄT\Netzwerkdienst), also erasing the values in the boxes for "password" and "repeat password"
4. click OK

If I now try to start the service, it starts successfully.

However I need to get my service registered automatically so that it uses the networkservice-account.

Am I doing something wrong? Is there another way to do this?

Please also note that I already took care of giving the Network-service account the right to logon as a service before the actions stated in this question. The account does not just get the right to logon as a service because I manually entered the account name and accepted the messagebox that normally pops up to let me know that the account just received the right.

New! I've added this with which you could help me by trying it out yourself:

With this script you can test this out yourself by creating a service from notepad.exe:

```
$secpasswd = (new-object System.Security.SecureString)
$SID = [System.Security.Principal.WellKnownSidType]::NetworkServiceSid
$Account = new-object system.security.principal.securityidentifier($SID, $null)
$NetworkServiceName = $Account.Translate([system.security.principal.ntaccount]).value 
$mycreds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($NetworkServiceName, $secpasswd)
New-Service -Name test1 -BinaryPathName C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe -Description testDescription -StartupType Manual -Credential $mycreds
```

Be sure to give the NetworkService account the right to logon as service though.

Do you get an error when starting the service afterwards? Is it the dependency error which makes no sense or is it something different?

Comment: Have you tried with `NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE` ?

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Meanwhile I tried it and it failed. When I now execute new-service command with 'NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE' the resulting error is something like this (Translated by me from german): "The Service 'MyServiceName' cannot be created because of an error: The account name is incorrect or does not exist or the password is incorrect" - The execution of the new-service method is successful if I run it like stated above (with the german name of the service)

Comment: Just tried your testing code as admin on my Dutch Windows 10 machine (PowerShell 5.1) and I cannot reproduce the error. Everything works as expected and yes, the `$NetworkServiceName` shows `NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE` (international, not localized to Dutch)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the Cim methods. they may help you get to what you need:

```
$Arguments = @{

DesktopInteract =$false ;
DisplayName = "notepad Test" ;
#ErrorControl =" " ;
#LoadOrderGroup =" " ;
#LoadOrderGroupDependencies =" " ;
Name ="Notepad" ;
PathName ="C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe" ;
ServiceDependencies = $Null ;
#ServiceType = "Own Process"#[int32]16 ; #ownService
StartMode ="Manual" ;
StartName ="NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService" ;# ([System.Security.Principal.WellKnownSidType]::BuiltinAdministratorsSid).tostring() ;
#StartPassword = $Null

};

 Invoke-CimMethod -ClassName win32_service -methodname Create -Arguments $Arguments
```

To remove the service via Cim:

```
$x =Get-CimInstance -ClassName win32_service -filter "name like '%note%'"
Invoke-CimMethod -InputObject $x -MethodName delete
```

Should you have errors refer to this page for what the error codes mean:

Errors on create can be found here (22) is the one I ran into until I figured out the right means.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/create-method-in-class-win32-service

To see how the items are set so you can get to your answer you need (except for the password):

```
Get-CimInstance -ClassName win32_service -filter  'Name like "%note%"' | select *
```

---

```
Name                    : Notepad
Status                  : OK
ExitCode                : 0
DesktopInteract         : False
ErrorControl            : Ignore
PathName                : C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe
ServiceType             : Own Process
StartMode               : Manual
Caption                 : notepad Test
Description             : 
InstallDate             : 
CreationClassName       : Win32_Service
Started                 : False
SystemCreationClassName : Win32_ComputerSystem
SystemName              : 
AcceptPause             : False
AcceptStop              : False
DisplayName             : notepad Test
ServiceSpecificExitCode : 0
StartName               : NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService
State                   : Stopped
TagId                   : 0
CheckPoint              : 0
DelayedAutoStart        : False
ProcessId               : 0
WaitHint                : 0
PSComputerName          : 
CimClass                : root/cimv2:Win32_Service
CimInstanceProperties   : {Caption, Description, InstallDate, Name...}
CimSystemProperties     : Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimSystemProperties
```